# REGEX - how to match exacly 3 words from url?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to match with regex exacly 3 words from search phrase from url but not match 4 or more. URL can have some variations. The problem is shown as below. Regex should match and not match following examples:

```
SHOULD MATCH:
https://example.com/search=any%20url%20encoded_word-here
https://example.com/search=any%20url%20encoded_word-here%20
https://example.com/search=z%C5%82oty%20z%C5%82oty%20z%C5%82oty
https://example.com/search=z%C5%82oty%20z%C5%82ota%20%C5%82ata
https://example.com/search=any%20%20word%20%20here
https://example.com/search=any%20word%20here&color=blue
https://example.com/search=any-1st%20word_2nd%20here3

SHOULD NOT MATCH:
https://example.com/search=one%20two%20three%20four
https://example.com/search=one%20%20two%20%20three%20%20four
https://example.com/search=one%20%20two%20three%20%20four
https://example.com/search=one%20%20two%20%20three%20%20four
https://example.com/search=one%20two%20three%20four&color=blue
https://example.com/search=z%C5%82oty%20z%C5%82oty%20z%C5%82oty%20word
```

Started here https://regex101.com/r/0qzCJV/1 but I have no idea how to not match on conditions. Can you pls help me guys?

Comment: What determines word boundary in your `URL`? In other words, what's the separator between words in search? Once I see `%20` and once `&`

Comment: Something like `.*/search=(?:(?:(?!%20).)*(?:%20|$)+){3}$`?

Comment: Or, `.*/search=((?:(?!%20).)*)(?:%20)+((?:(?!%20).)*)(?:%20)+((?:(?!%20).)*)(?:%20)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qzCJV/2))?

Comment: word boundary is space (%20) - thanks it's working now - saved my life :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(((?!%20).)*(%20)+){2}((?!%20).)*(%20)?$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/fwz9cEV8YMdB8T).

This uses a negative look ahead to match up to `%20`, then any number of `%20`, and all that twice. Then finish with anything not `%20`, except there may be %20 at the end.

---

Note: Your examples non-matches did not include urls with *less than* 3, eg

https://example.com/search=one%20two

Comment: thanks, the matter was to get only 3-word phrases, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead to fail the match when there are 3 `%20` followed by at least 1 more character:

```sh
^(?!(?:.+?%20){3}.)(?:.+?%20){2}.+?(?:%20)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qzCJV/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!(?:.+?%20){3}.)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match when we have 3 occurrences of `%20` followed by at least 1 character
- `(?:.+?%20){2}`: Match 1+ of any characters followed by `%20`. Repeat this match 2 times to match 2 words
- `.+?`: Match 1+ of any characters
- `(?:%20)?`: Match optional `%20` before end
- `$`: End

Or use **possessive quantifier** to reduce backtracking:

```
^(?!(?:.+?%20){3}+.)(?:.+?%20){2}.+?(?:%20)?$
```